# What is the correct method to wrap a heap of code into a variable

Tags: php

I'm working with a shopping cart script that doesn't let me add php to the template files. The method used is to create `$GLOBALS` within the class files and call them from the tpl files. What I need to do is the following.

`$GLOBALS['DiscountedPrice']` needs to be equal to that chunk of code that follows. I've tried a few syntax options to try and wrap it up, but it breaks because the same syntax is used inside the chunk of code.

```
$GLOBALS['DiscountedPrice'] =  $query = mysql_query("
             SELECT *
             FROM isc_customer_group_discounts
             WHERE `catorprodid` = '%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%'
             AND `customergroupid` = 1
             AND `discounttype` = 'PRODUCT'
             ");
$discounted_price = '';
while($proddisc = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $discperc = $proddisc['4'];
    $discmeth = $proddisc['6'];
    if($discmeth = 'percent') {
        $discperc = $proddisc['4']/100;
        $discounted_price = $row['prodprice'] * $discperc;
        $GLOBALS['DiscountedPrice'] = $discounted_price;
    }elseif ($discmeth = 'price') {
        $discounted_price = $row['prodprice'] - $discperc;
        $GLOBALS['DiscountedPrice'] = $discounted_price;
    }elseif ($discmeth = 'fixed') {
        $discounted_price = $discperc;
        $GLOBALS['DiscountedPrice'] = $discounted_price;
    }};
```

Comment: I don't get it. "The variable must be equal to the code"? What does that mean?

Comment: are you trying to get an array of results perhaps? `$GLOBALS['DiscountedPrice'][] =  $discounted_price;`

Comment: I actually need that whole string of code to go in and be executed on the page. The template has the <li>product details</li> but i can't add code to the template page. i need to pass it in via the GLOBALS

Comment: So you want that block of code to be contained _as a string_ in the variable `$GLOBALS['DiscountedPrice']`, which you then intend to `eval()` inside your template?

Comment: yes Michael i think thats what i need. I've tried all the suggestions so far, along with a heap of other ideas. Having no luck. I just need to get that code inside the template to run it there.

Comment: @jason3w I think there's a huge mistake in your software design. If you need to store and execute PHP as template files then use .php-files instead of storing the program code inside some variable and evaluate it. Maybe you should ask a new question related to your basic problem – what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think i am just trying something that's not really possible. I need to rethink i guess. Find a new way of looking at this. Obviously by the downvotes i take it the question is pretty silly. I've only been doing php for 1.5 months. So learning still. Thanks for the help. I'll update question once i work out what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$GLOBALS['DiscountedPrice'] .= $discounted_price;
```

Use a dot to concatenate the string as the loop goes round.  (no space between . and =)

EDIT.

Possibly I have not fully understood you question, but if you want to continually join strings this is what you'd do.

```
$discounted_price = ''; // you start with an empty string
while($proddisc = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$discperc = $proddisc['4'];
$discmeth = $proddisc['6'];
if($discmeth = 'percent') {
    $discperc = $proddisc['4']/100;
    $discounted_price = $row['prodprice'] * $discperc;
// and now you concat (join) it to the new value
    $GLOBALS['DiscountedPrice'] .= $discounted_price;
}elseif ($discmeth = 'price') {
    $discounted_price = $row['prodprice'] - $discperc;
    $GLOBALS['DiscountedPrice'] .= $discounted_price;
}elseif ($discmeth = 'fixed') {
    $discounted_price = $discperc;
    $GLOBALS['DiscountedPrice'] .= $discounted_price;
}};
```

Comment: Cool idea! So everywhere a ; exists how do i include it in the concatenated string?